# How to include a php file with bootstrap content in another php file

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am having trouble including a php file with my navigation bar in another php file.

Here's the navigation file:

```
<?php echo "
<html>
<head>
<nav class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top " role = "navigation">
<div class = "container-fluid">

  <div class = "navbar-header navbar-right">
    <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href = "index.php"> About Me </a></li>
      <li><a href = "contact.php"> Contacts </a></li>
      <li><a href = "skills.php"> Skills </a></li>
      <li><a href = "portfolio.php"> Portfolio </a></li>
      <li><a href = "case_studies.php"> Case Studies</a></li>
      <li><a href = "resume.php"> Resume </a></li>
      <li><a href = "extras.php"> Extras</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
</nav>
</head>
<script src = "js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src = "js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</html>
" ?>
```

I have this line in my index.php file

```
<?php 
include"navigation.php"; 
?>
```

I have checked the referencing of the file and all refereces seem ok.

Comment: What's your question / what errors are you seeing?

Comment: correct your html with php first.

Comment: Step one. Learn to use PHP [strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: There  are no errors. Just the nav bar wont appera

Comment: @MillerAdulu There are most definitely syntax errors in what you have provided.

Comment: 2 mistakes in your navigation file. 1. use single quotes like `<?php echo '` you html code and 2. semicolon miss in last `</html>';
?>`

Comment: I have removed the php opening and closing lines to remain with the pure html code.  Then i have used                                                                <php echo include ("includes/navigationbar.php"); ?> to display it and it workd well now. Thank you @JonStirling.

Comment: @MillerAdulu I don't think you need the `echo` before the `include`.

Comment: I have changed, the code and removed to echo include, but exactly as the code is I tweaked around to make it work using the echo include. My most current version has the echo include deleted and only the include.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I appreciate you professionalism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

" should be '

```
        <?php echo '
        <html>
        <head>
        <nav class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top " role = "navigation">
        <div class = "container-fluid">

          <div class = "navbar-header navbar-right">
            <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href = "index.php"> About Me </a></li>
              <li><a href = "contact.php"> Contacts </a></li>
              <li><a href = "skills.php"> Skills </a></li>
              <li><a href = "portfolio.php"> Portfolio </a></li>
              <li><a href = "case_studies.php"> Case Studies</a></li>
              <li><a href = "resume.php"> Resume </a></li>
              <li><a href = "extras.php"> Extras</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
        </head>
        <script src = "js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src = "js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        </html>
        ';?>
```

**include the file**

```
<?php
include 'navigation.php';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you closing the HTML tag within your navigation file?

It's probably best having a 'master' application template, which you include the html tag, the head and the body, then inside the body include your scripts at the bottom and include your navigation bar using the PHP tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php try{
            if( !file_exists("navigation.php") )
            {  throw new Exception("Unable to include resources header");  }
            else{  require_once("navigation.php");  }
            }catch(Exception $e){
                echo $e->getMessage();
                exit;
            }
?>
```

Please try this this will definitely work.This is working in my case.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to debug the error and add an echo line for the file in index.php.

Comment: always welcome. your problem is solved or not ? please accept the ans too.

Comment: I can only accept one answer. I used this method to find the error in the text file that added some recommentations from another answer. Unfortunately there's no way to accept a combination of answers.